# Condition evaluating incorrectly (Lua 4)

Tags: lua, ternary

I am trying to use this function in Lua 4:

```
function ternary(cond, T, F)
    if cond then return T else return F end
end
```

In this context:

```
loadHW1 = false
print(ternary(loadHW1 == true, "this should not appear", nil))
```

However, the text always gets printed when instead I expect the result to be `nil`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[ed]

I switched to this but still get a "this is true" result:

```
loadHW1 = 0
print(ternary(loadHW1, "this is true", "this is false"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua 4 doesn't have Booleans: they were introduced in Lua 5.

In Lua 4, only nil is false; anything else, including 0, is true.

In your code,
`false` and `true` are being interpreted as undefined global variables and so both evaluate to nil. Therefore, `loadHW1 == true` becomes `nil == nil`, which is true, and so `ternary` receives 1 for `cond`.

If you want to use `false` and `true` in Lua 4, define them as follows:

```
false = nil
 true = 1
```

Comment: I updated the question. Switching to numbers I am still getting a true result when it should be false.

Comment: @posfan12, only nil is false; 0 is true.